# Anchors within the document and their position

Tags: html, css

On the following website, [www.josecvega.com](http://www.josecvega.com), I have a navigation bar with years that link to sections on that same page. Unfortunately it is not working they way I hoped, when the user selects a year it moves to the section of the page and puts that section on the top of the page, I have a **fixed** div on the top of the page that covers the sections and prevents it from properly displaying. What can I do for this to work?

It hard to explain my situation, but it can be seen by going to [www.josecvega.com](http://www.josecvega.com) and clicking one of the years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your anchors earlier in the file. Perhaps use a fixed-height element (the same height as your header) in the margin just before each section and apply the anchor to that.

Or use a script run after the jump and scroll back down X pixels.

Or use a frameset to display the fixed header rather than the `position:fixed` div you are using now.

I would probably do the latter.

Answer (score 0):

your header (class=bannercontainer") is position:fixed

so this element will not scroll.
if you now click on a year it scrolls the page behind the header.
probably position:fixed is not what you want

Comment: I want to keep it fixed. I would like it for when a year is clicked for the content to show in the "proper" area.